# How to find the original population if it increases with a constant rate?

Tags: finance

The population increases by 5% every year. What was the population in 1982, if in 1985 it was 1,85220?

My working:

```
     population in 1985 = 1,85,220
     rate=5%
     time = 3yrs

  ( A=P(1-R/100)^n )
     therefore, population in 1982 = 185220(1 - 5/100)^3
                          = 158802.9975
```

obviously that's wrong, but where's the problem?

Comment: You mixed up formula's for depreciation & compound interest. An asset $x$ depreciates every year to $x(1-R).$  That's $x$ multiplied by a fraction $< 1.$ An asset $x$ (or population) *increases* every year to $x(1+R).$ That's $x$ multiplied by a constant $> 1.$

Comment: If $x$ is decreased by $y\%$ to obtain $z$, then $z$ increased by $y\%$ is *not* $x$ (try it with $x=100$ and $y=10\%$). So, starting in 1985, decreasing by $5\%$ each year to 1982 is not the same as starting in 1982 and increasing by $5\%$ per year to 1985.

Comment: @ David Mitra so then how do i proceed?

Comment: As in Williams answer: take the original value (in 1982). You know that if you increase by $5\%$ per year, you get 185220. This gives you an equation whose variable is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a basic error: If you increase a quantity $P_1$ by $y\%$ of itself to obtain the new value $P_2$, then decreasing $P_2$ by $y\%$ of itself does not get you back to $P_1$ (because you also decrease by $y\%$ of the increase previously gained). For example, increasing $100$ by $10\%$ of itself gives you $110$, but decreasing $110$ by $10\%$ of itself gives you $99$.

You need to start with the 1982 value, call this $x$, and then find an equation in $x$ and solve. William's answer explains how to do this.

(Incidentally, why do you say your answer is "obviously wrong"?)

Comment: the answer is obviously wrong because the population can't be in decimal

Comment: @Nirvan Of course, silly me :)

Comment: ok so i got the answer by doing this:
185220=x(1+5/100) = 160000,
thanks

Comment: @Nirvan You want $(1+5/100)^3$ there (three years of increase). So the equation is $x(1+5/100)^3=185220$. Solving this for $x$ gives $x=185220/(1.05)^3=160000$. Note, it would be wrong to write $185220=x(1+5/100)^3\color{maroon}{=160000}$. You have an *equation* here. Its solution needs to be written as a separate statement.

Comment: i don't understand what you're saying is missing

Comment: @Nirvan The equation is $ 185220=x(1+5/100)^3 $, not $185220=x(1+5/100) $ as you wrote (you forgot the exponent). My second comment regarded how you wrote the solution: writing $ 185220=x(1+5/100)^3 =160000$ is wrong (you are saying in particular that $185220=160000$ then). You need to write something like "$ 185220=x(1+5/100)^3$ so $x=160000$" instead.

Comment: oh, ok i see , well then thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To increase by $5$ percents is to multiply by $1.05$. This occurred for 3 years. So you obtain the equation:

$(1.05)^{3}x = 185220$

Solve for $x$ and this is the population in 1982.